# Arquillian Chameleon Container with Java 11

Tags: java, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

we have following problem with starting a Arquillian-Test with Chameleon-Container and Wildfly 14 in a Java 11.0.2 (OpenJDK 11) environment. We use maven as the build tool.

After starting the test, it stopped with following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ arquillian-tutorial ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running de.evodion.arquillian.example.GreeterTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.581 s <<< FAILURE! - in de.evodion.arquillian.example.GreeterTest
[ERROR] de.evodion.arquillian.example.GreeterTest  Time elapsed: 1.579 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Date
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
```

In a Java 8 environment, the setting works.
We already changed the surefire plugin version from 3.0.0M3 back to 2.22.0, because this plugin version lead to the same error.

A minimal pom to test this behaviour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.evodion.arquillian.example</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.org.wildfly>14.0.1.Final</version.org.wildfly>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <jboss.home>${project.build.directory}\wildfly-${version.org.wildfly}</jboss.home>
                    <module.path>${project.build.directory}\wildfly-${version.org.wildfly}\modules</module.path>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-chameleon-junit-container-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The arquillian xml to use with the chameleon container:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="chameleon" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">--add-modules java.se</property>
            <property name="chameleonTarget">wildfly:14.0.1.Final:managed</property>
            <property name="serverConfig">standalone-full.xml</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

We tried using wildfly 16 in the arquillian.xml file, but that leads to the same error. We also tried using the "new" junit 4.13-beta-2, same error. 
We tried using java 11.0.1(OpenJDK) and the release canditate java 12 (OpenJDK).
In the arquillian.xml file we tried adding the sql module with

```
<property name="javaVmArguments">--add-modules java.se,java.sql</property>
```

still no improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuck with same problem. To my knowlede Arquillian Chameleon still
not capable to run on Java 11 (only Java 8).

Comment: Agree with that. I looked at the issues for the chameleon project on github and found an open issue for jdk9+ support (since May '18 [chameleon-project](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-chameleon/issues/90))  
I then checked out the sources for the project and looked into the ContainerLoader Class mentioned in the issue. A simple change like the comment in the issue suggest can't be made because this project is build with Java 7 and there is no static method ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader().  

Thank you for your Answer. Think that was very helpful.

Comment: Seems to be fixed (https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-chameleon/issues/90). We are using now the Chameleon Adapter + Wildfly 16.0.0.Final as remote server with arquillian. (Managed seems to work also).